# How do I make a sour mash with lactic acid?

Tags: all-grain

I'd like to make a sour beer, and I have a bunch of lactic acid from a previous brew (never used it).

Aside from letting the mash sit overnight, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add lactic acid directly, but everything I've read says that gives you a much "simpler" kind of sour instead of the complex sour that comes from genuinely spoiling the grain.

A member of my homebrew club made a brown sour that we tried recently and it was really good. What he did to sour was to put a wet mash sit in the oven with just the pilot light going for 24 hours or so and then boiled that. The result is that everything in the fermenter is still sanitary, but it was still soured a little.

I would try letting it go longer as I could have gone for more sour than what he had.